# how to add a line into a series of text files after a variable line

Tags: batch-file, variables

I want to add a line to a series of text files in subfolders after a variable line :

each text file is named `data.txt`

my text files contain such lines :

```
some text ...
[data.0 = fx_abc]
[data.1 = fx_xyz]
...
[data.n = fx_pqr]
... some text
```

each text file has a varied n'th data line,

all I want to add is the (n+1)'th data line after those n'th lines 
in each text files :

```
[data.(n+1) = fx_some text]
```

I want to use a batch file to carry out this task.

Comment: Kind of a confusing examples. So if the last line is `[data.100 = fx_pqr]`, what will the next line be?

Comment: [data.101 = 'some constant text data']

Answer (score 0):

get the last counter, increase it by one and append the new line:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
REM for every textfile here and all subfolders...
for /r %%f in (data.txt) do (
  REM a default value if no match found:
  set "last=none"
  REM get last counter:
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=. " %%a in ('type "%%f"^|findstr /b /c:"[data."') do set "last=%%a"
  REM if not default value...
  if not "!last!" == "none" (
    REM increase counter:
    set /a last+=1 
    REM append line:
    echo [data.!last! = some_text]>>"%%f"
  ) 
)
```

**EDIT** to match last comment and canged question. Inserting into a file is not possible, you have to rewrite the whole file. This might have a bad performance with many/big files.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
REM for every textfile here and all subfolders...
for /r %%f in (data.txt) do (
  REM a default value if no match found:
  set "last=none"
  REM get last counter:
  for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=. " %%a in ('type "%%f"^|findstr /b /c:"[data."') do (
    set "last=%%b"
    set "line=%%a.%%b %%c"
    set /a new=last+1 
  ) 
  REM read file line by line and rewrite it:
  ( 
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%%f") do (
      echo %%a
      REM if that was the last "[data" line, add the new line: 
      if "%%a"=="!line!" echo [data.!new! = some_text]
    )
  )>"%%f.new"
  REM move the output file to the original name [/y = overwrite]
  move /y "%%f.new" "%%f" >nul
)
```

Comment: can we place this (n+1)th new last line right after the (n)th line instead of directly to the end of the text files, since there are still some other text lines before and after this [data.n = 'some text' ] data group.

Comment: thanks a lot, you are a veritable wizard. i'll give it a go tomorrow since i'm away from my pc now. it seems like it is virtually impossible to directly add the (n+1)th line after the (n)th without rewriting the entirety of the text files.

Comment: not just *virtually* impossible. Its because ot how the information is stored on the disk (sequential). Technically, it would be enough to rewrite "only" the data after the added bytes, but I don't know any tool that messes with that (concerning textfiles. Databases work different). It's easier to just rewrite the whole file.

Comment: what if i changed the extensions from .txt to .cfg ( I am very much able to, indeed ) ? would it make any difference in the way the added (n+1)th lines are dealt with ?

Comment: doesn't make any difference. A textfile is a textfile and the extension is - well, just a part of it's name.

Comment: first version works fine but append the new data.(n+1) at the bottom of the text file, not aimed. second version totally fails though. I thank you very much for taking your time to find a solution.

Comment: I forgot `/r` to make it process subfolders too . Away from that, it works fine for me. What problem do you have?